# Need an efficient way in R to convert coloured utf-8 emoji characters to their default skin

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, emoji, data-cleaning

Is there any efficient way to get rid of colored emojis from vectors and make them to their standard form? Please see two output for instance, I maybe not using appropriate terms. Currently I am doing like this:

```r
library(rjson)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

# this function gets name from emojis one at a time
emoji_json_file <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ToadHanks/emojisLib_json/master/emojis.json"
json_data <- rjson::fromJSON(paste(readLines(emoji_json_file), collapse = "")) #read line by line make 

# gets the name i.e. get_name_from_emoji("") output should be "yum"

get_name_from_emoji <- function(emoji_unicode, emoji_data = json_data) {

  emoji_evaluated <- stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(emoji_unicode) 

  vector_of_emoji_names_and_characters <- unlist(
    lapply(json_data, function(x){
      x$char
    })
  )

  name_of_emoji <- attr(
    which(vector_of_emoji_names_and_characters == emoji_evaluated)[1],
    "names"
  )

  return(name_of_emoji)
}

# Fill an empty vector with names
emoji_pouch_copy <- c("","","","","","") #we can't render U+1F3FB (light-skin graft), U+1F3FF (dark-skin graft) here that's why "?"
emoji_keywords_pouch <- c() 
for(i in 1: length(emoji_pouch_copy)){
  emoji_keywords_pouch <- c(emoji_keywords_pouch, get_name_from_emoji(emoji_pouch_copy[i]))
}

emoji_keywords_pouch #output: "shushing","point_down_fairly_dark","point_right_dark","fu_light","dark_skin_tone","light_skin_tone" 

#Function to remove the skin tones
remove_all_skins <- function(string, pattern) {
  str_replace_all(string, pattern, "000")
}

#remove these and their nativ renders at a positions
skin_tones <- c("medium_skin_tone", "fairly_dark_skin_tone", "dark_skin_tone", "fairly_light_skin_tone", "light_skin_tone", "_light","_dark","_medium","_fairly") 

emoji_keywords_pouch <- remove_all_skins(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[1])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- remove_all_skins(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[2])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- remove_all_skins(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[3])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- remove_all_skins(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[4])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- remove_all_skins(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[5])

emoji_keywords_pouch <- emoji_keywords_pouch[emoji_keywords_pouch != "000"] #free the memory

#It has to be this order, otherwise good strings will go bad in the variable containing keywords
emoji_keywords_pouch <- stringr::str_remove_all(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[6])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- stringr::str_remove_all(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[7])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- stringr::str_remove_all(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[8])
emoji_keywords_pouch <- stringr::str_remove_all(emoji_keywords_pouch, skin_tones[9])

#Reverse the function get_name... to get_emoji and rebuild the emoji_pouch
#i.e. get_emoji_from_name("yum") output should be ""

get_emoji_from_name <- function(emoji_name, emoji_data = json_data) {

  vector_of_emoji_names_and_characters <- unlist(
    lapply(json_data, function(x){
      x$char
    })
  )

  emoji_character <- unname(
    vector_of_emoji_names_and_characters[
      names(vector_of_emoji_names_and_characters) == emoji_name
      ]
  )

  return(emoji_character)
}

#reset the original emoji_...copy to include standard tones
emoji_pouch_copy <- c()

for(i in 1: length(emoji_keywords_pouch)){
  # Sys.sleep(1)
  emoji_pouch_copy <- c(emoji_pouch_copy, get_emoji_from_name(emoji_keywords_pouch[i]))
}

#All of the skin tones are removed, because there are no standad skin tones
emoji_pouch_copy #output: """" "" ""

#Finished
```

In a nutshell I am going from emojis to their names. Then clean their names by removing skin conditions, and then reverting back to their emoji form. I have close to 1000 emojis, and for loop is causing like 5 seconds delay. Is there some package that gets this work done much better than I can?

Comment: What you could do is to create a translation table. Then just replace the values with the values from the table. Takes a bit of initial work, but if you have to run the code often, it will be faster in the long run.

Comment: Hello thanks for the feedback! I thought of that as my initial workaround but it created issues when I give my file to Windows people for some reason. Luckily JB down here showed the ```sapply()``` and it certainly works better than my approach. Appreciate your input friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I got your question. But you can get rid of different coloring like this:

Starting with the data

```
library(rjson)

# this function gets name from emojis one at a time
emoji_json_file <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ToadHanks/emojisLib_json/master/emojis.json"
json_data <- rjson::fromJSON(paste(readLines(emoji_json_file), collapse = "")) #read line by line make
```

Extract just the emojis:

```
emojis <- sapply(json_data, function(x) x$char)
```

Now the way these are coloured is by sticking twoUnicode characters together. For example:

```
emojis[114]
#> raised_hands_light 
#> "<U+0001F64C><U+0001F3FB>"
```

We can split these with `strsplit(emojis, "")`. This will result in a list with vector length 1 if there is no colouring and length 2 if an emoji is coloured or otherwise changed (e.g., male/female). We only keep the first element from each vector in the list:

```
emojis_clean <- sapply(strsplit(emojis, ""), "[[", 1)
```

Now the emoji 114 looks like this:

```
emojis_clean[114]
#> raised_hands_light 
#>     "<U+0001F64C>"
```

## extra: problems with flags

The above approach is fast but dumb. It does not recognise when an combined emoji is rightfully combined. Flags for example consist of two Unicode characters put together. There are probably other examples. We can replace these with the original vector by looking for some keywords in the `names` of the emoji vector:

```
# Look for flags
flags <- grep("flag", names(emojis))

# replace flags with original values
emojis_clean[flags] <- emojis[flags]
```

This approach can be used for other types of emojis.

Comment: Dang, you're like light showing me way. All of my recent questions were answered by you. Really appreciate you helping me sir. Sorry about the question, basically I wanted to the default form of the emojis, and get rid of their associated coloured conjunction, if there is one. Your answer worked, and very efficiently too.

Comment: It's no coincidence . You ask good questions about my field of expertise. Here the title was super clear but then I was a bit confused if this is really what you want towards the end of the question. Glad I could help!

Comment: It gets the task done, but it messed up the flags of countries. But I think that can be prevented with stopping case. Like stop sapplying before this index. Edit, thanks, your comment came while I was typing.

Comment: If you're using a Linux distro and ```View(emojis_clean)```  you would see what I mean. It also changed England's flag to a black pirate flag 

Comment: So basically what Brexit is supposed to accomplish . The approach above is fast but dumb. I didn't scroll far enough down to see any flags in the viewer. One thing you could do is to select the original version if a keyword is present in the name. Maybe "flag"?

Comment: LMFAO! Yep. Good idea, I do have a keyword list in that json file I edited. So I can skip over char if the "flag" keyword is present in keywords list.

Comment: I quickly updated the answer to include the flags problem.

Comment: Better than I ever can. You're the boss, thanks a lot for helping all this time. God bless!